Failing to install python-docx due to failed building wheel for lxml
Python version : Python 3.12.3
macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
I was trying to install python-docx and encountered the following error message regarding lxml.
   Collecting python-docx
  Using cached python_docx-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.0 kB)
Collecting lxml<=4.9.2,>=3.1.0 (from python-docx)
  Using cached lxml-4.9.2.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting typing-extensions>=4.9.0 (from python-docx)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.11.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Using cached python_docx-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
Using cached typing_extensions-4.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Building wheel for lxml (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for lxml (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [176 lines of output]
      <string>:117: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\.'
      <string>:67: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Building lxml version 4.9.2.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.29
      Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/lib
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/html
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/objectify.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/etree.pyx -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/public-api.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xmlid.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cleanup.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xslt.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xpath.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/debug.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/serializer.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/classlookup.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/saxparser.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/objectpath.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/relaxng.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xinclude.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/iterparse.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/parser.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/dtd.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xmlerror.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/readonlytree.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/extensions.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xmlschema.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/schematron.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/docloader.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/nsclasses.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/parsertarget.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/xsltext.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/proxy.pxi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/lxml
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
      src/lxml/etree.c:262394:36: error: no member named 'curexc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'
              PyObject* tmp_tb = tstate->curexc_traceback;
                                 ~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:262397:21: error: no member named 'curexc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'
                  tstate->curexc_traceback = tb;
                  ~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:263340:53: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
              const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)op1)->ob_digit;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:263457:53: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
              const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)op1)->ob_digit;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:265182:53: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
              const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)op1)->ob_digit;
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:267536:55: error: no member named 'gi_code' in 'PyGenObject'
          if (PyGen_CheckExact(obj) && ((PyGenObject*)obj)->gi_code && ((PyCodeObject *)((PyGenObject*)obj)->gi_code)->co_flags & CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE) {
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:267536:104: error: no member named 'gi_code' in 'PyGenObject'
          if (PyGen_CheckExact(obj) && ((PyGenObject*)obj)->gi_code && ((PyCodeObject *)((PyGenObject*)obj)->gi_code)->co_flags & CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE) {
                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:268588:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:268643:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:268897:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:268952:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269093:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269148:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269289:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269344:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269523:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269578:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269757:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      src/lxml/etree.c:269812:55: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
                  const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)x)->ob_digit;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      20 errors generated.
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      creating var
      creating var/folders
      creating var/folders/rg
      creating var/folders/rg/44f312ss6jddp8pnjhvd8qqw0000gn
      creating var/folders/rg/44f312ss6jddp8pnjhvd8qqw0000gn/T
      cc -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/rg/44f312ss6jddp8pnjhvd8qqw0000gn/T/xmlXPathInit8gw85dwa.c -o var/folders/rg/44f312ss6jddp8pnjhvd8qqw0000gn/T/xmlXPathInit8gw85dwa.o
      cc var/folders/rg/44f312ss6jddp8pnjhvd8qqw0000gn/T/xmlXPathInit8gw85dwa.o -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/usr/lib -lxml2 -o a.out
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
Failed to build lxml
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I updated my macOS system to the latest. Ensured Xcode is installed. Tried to uninstall and reinstall lxml. But the same error persists. Anyone encountered the same?

solved afterwards. Basically I uninstalled the latest python and installed an older version... no issue anymore

I met the same question.Find that it's just because the new python-docx can't support the new lxml<5.2.0>.Maybe it just refer to lxml<=4.9.2,>=3.1.0.
I try install the old version python-docx(python_docx_1-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl),then  done.

thx! Yeah we tackled in similar ways!
